# Save landscape application state while device will unlocked from lock state

Tags: android, android-savedstate

My application has only landscaped mode. And there are some edit text fields on the screen. I am filling some contents in edittext box and lock the device and When i unlock the device and i found the my application screen with blank edit text box. Please help me how to store data while application resume from device lock mode to unlock mode.
Sorry for poor English.
Thank you.

Comment: try [freezesText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:freezesText)

Comment: Freezetext is not working in my case. If you have any other idea then please tell me

Comment: then there's always `onSaveInstanceState` and you can do it manually ;)

Answer (score 0):

In this problem I found a new issue fragment is popback stacked while orientation changed.  So I convert fragment to activity and implement  Onsavedinstancestate for storing values on activity rotation.